# Form helper select box outputs incorrectly

Tags: forms, cakephp, select, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I decided to move a select box out of one view and stick it in another. However, whilst it worked in one form is doesn't in the new one. I'll just get straight to the point:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('Basket.delivery', array('options' => array( '13' => 'United Kingdom (£13)', '45' => 'European Union (£45)', '75' => 'International (£75)'))); 
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Outputs:

```
<select name="data[Basket][delivery]" id="BasketDelivery">
<option value="13"></option>
<option value="45"></option>
<option value="75"></option>
</select>
```

Now why is that then ??? :(

Comment: I know so far it's being caused by the '£' symbol

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use [Currency Special characters code](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cur.htm) to show the options in dropdown which are part of the [ISO 8859-1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) standard.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('Basket.delivery', array('options' => array( '13' => 'United Kingdom (&pound;13)', '45' => 'European Union (&pound;45)', '75' => 'International (&pound;75)'))); 
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

If you are also experiencing problems with the form itself you can try to pass the model name to the `Form->create()` function:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(Basket);
    ......
```

Read the [CakePHP book entry for FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html). There is the [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper) too.
Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: It's a strange one because I can achieve the '£' on one page but not another. I am beginning to think it might be related to the css and or JavaScript that's involved; I am using twitter bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).